# Off canvas layout with sticky column

Tags: css, susy-sass

The layout I'm working on is an off-canvas type layout where part of the information is transitioned into view when needed, very popular on smaller screens as smartphones. My code is based on the example from this [blog post](http://www.zell-weekeat.com/off-canvas-layouts-susy/). The problem is to keep the container that is off-canvas at a fixed position while the main container can be scrollable vertically. In order to illustrate the problem I have created a quick [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LiEqx).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="transformer">
  <div class="off-canvas">
     Content off canvas goes here
  </div>
  <div class="main">
     Main content
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Would greatly appreciate any pointers to a solution for this.

The CSS framework in use is [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/).